# php ftp_nlist timeout in Heroku

Tags: php, heroku, ftp, timeout

### What

I'm trying to do a pretty basic **ftp** reading in **Heroku**.

### Code:

```
$ftp = ftp_connect($config['domain']);

$login = ftp_login($ftp,$config['ftp_user'],$config['ftp_pass']);

ftp_pasv($ftp, true);

$contents = ftp_nlist($ftp, "/");
for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($contents) ; $i++)
        echo "<li>" . substr($contents[$i],1) . "</li>";

ftp_close($ftp);
```

### Heroku Error

```
2015-05-19T07:26:01.678102+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/" host=xxx-ftp.herokuapp.com request_id=xxxxx-364a-48f8-8e2a-383affb0789f fwd="xx.12.8.106" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0
2015-05-19T07:26:31.739770+00:00 app[web.1]: [Tue May 19 07:26:31.738789 2015] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 186:tid 140199224919808] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 10.127.183.84:42907] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling)
2015-05-19T07:26:31.853475+00:00 app[web.1]: [19-May-2015 07:26:31 UTC] PHP Warning:  ftp_nlist(): php_connect_nonb() failed: Operation now in progress (115) in /app/list.php on line 26
```

### Facts

1. The connection is ok (returning true)
2. Heroku is giving timeout only when ftp_nlist or ftp_rawlist is executed.
3. The login is ok
4. I've tried with and without `PASIVE` mode
5. Other basic commands as `PWD` are working ok
6. I've also tried by listing a more specific folder e.g: `ftp_nlist($conn,"/MyFolder");`
7. The amount of folder I'm trying to read and list is small.
8. The FTP server is responding in less than 2sec from other FTP clients
9. **The same code in other server (not heroku) works fine.**

Comment: You're saying you have tried `ftp_pasv($conn_id,true);`, yes?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work just fine for `ftp.mozilla.org` for instance:

```
$ftp = ftp_connect('ftp.mozilla.org');
$login_result = ftp_login($ftp, 'anonymous', '');
ftp_pasv($ftp, true);
var_dump(ftp_nlist($ftp, "/pub/mozilla.org/"));
```

Are you maybe hitting https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55651 with your destination FTP behind NAT?